# Argument of setkeys

Tags: package-writing, kvoptions

My motivation bases on the package `listings` (also my package `mdframed`). The package allows to define a style via `\lstset{foo}{options}`. Now I want to create a macro to expand the style `foo`. For example `\Apptolstset{foo}{more options}`.

I created the followings example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{testpackage.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{testpackage}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox,kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=test,prefix=test@}
\DeclareStringOption[\bfseries]{font}
\DeclareStringOption[\normalsize]{size}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*\relax
\newcommand\testsetup{\setkeys{test}}

\define@key{test}{loadstyle}{%
  \ifcsundef{test@style@#1}{}%
        {\expandafter\testsetup\expandafter{\csname test@style@#1\endcsname}}%
}
\newrobustcmd*\teststyle[2]{%
  \csdef{test@style@#1}{#2}%
}

\newrobustcmd*\apptodefinestyle[2]{%
 \ifcsundef{test@style@#1}%
   {}%
   {\csappto{test@style@#1}{,#2}}%
}


\newrobustcmd*\testresult[1]{{\test@font\test@size #1}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{testpackage}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\testresult{Hello World!}

\teststyle{new}{font=\bfseries\itshape}
\apptodefinestyle{new}{size=\Large}
\testsetup{loadstyle=new}

\testresult{Hello World!}

\end{document}
```

The error of this example is:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
\protect
l.35 \testsetup{loadstyle=new}
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
```

If I use the combination

```
\define@key{test}{loadstyle}{%
  \ifcsundef{test@style@#1}{}%
        {\csuse{test@style@#1}}%
}
\newrobustcmd*\teststyle[2]{%
  \csdef{test@style@#1}{\testsetup{#2}}%
}
```

everything will work. But with this combination I don't know how to define the command `\apptoteststyle` which should be expand the current style.

I hope the question is clear.

Comment: Usually you should start the question with a short explanation what you trying to achieve. Also, please always state what error you get. "Doesn't work without errors" isn't that helpful without the exact error you get.

Comment: The issue seems to be that you trying something like `\setkeys{test}{\test@style@new}` (because `#1`=`new`), i.e. feeding a macro to `\setkeys`. However it awaits *keys* instead. So use `\setkeys{test}{style@#1}` instead a define the style code using `\define@key{test}{style@new}[]{<code>}`.

Comment: In `\define@key{test}{loadstyle}{...}` you are calling `\setkeys{test}{...}` with an argument that's *not* in the form `key=value`. It's quite difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @egreg and @martinscharrer: The argument of `\setkeys` is saved in a macro in the form `key=value`.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Is my explanation clear now?

Comment: AFAIK, `\setkeys` doesn't perform expansion of its second argument. You have to expand it before making it available to `\setkeys`.

Comment: @egreg: I tried `\expandafter\testsetup\expandafter{\csuse{test@style@#1}}` with the same result. I hope you mean this.

Comment: One expansion step, say with `#1=new` would give `\testsetup{\csname test@style@new\endcsname}` which is still invalid. You need to expand twice or use `\expandafter\testsetup\expandafter{\csname test@style@#1\endcsname}` directly.

Comment: @egreg: with that you still end up with `\setkeys{test}{\test@style@new}`. Should be `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\testsetup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname test@style@#1\endcsname}`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @MartinScharrer You're right. Probably not the best way to go. :)

Comment: @MartinScharrer: This works well. Please provide an answer that I can accept ;-) -- I also changed the example in my question ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `\setkeys` macro doesn't expand its second argument. If you have a macro which holds the keys you need to expand it first. Note that `\csuse` adds one expansion step (as any macro does) so you should use the underlying `\csname ... \endcsname` directly. This must be expanded *twice*, once to create the macro from its name and then to expand the macro itself.

So do:

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\testsetup\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter{\csname test@style@#1\endcsname}
```